# Delete all records from a database without altering or dropping consistency constraints

Tags: mysql

while studying for my exam I came across a question that surprisingly never came up in my assignments and lab work. Below is an image link to the tables being used as it doesn't allow copy and pasting and I don't feel like typing them by hand (sorry).

[image]

The question wishes to drop all records in relation to Applicant number 105, but there are multiple constraints to bypass and as stated before I cant drop or modify the constraints. how does one work around this? Thank you.

Comment: I guess you need to find relevant records in `SNEEDED` and delete them, then in `SPOSSESSED` and delete them, and so on. In this way no constraints are violated. Or, if you can modify tables, you can apply `ON DELETE CASCADE` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), and just delete single record in `APPLICANT` -- other records will be found and removed by association. Depending on real-world task, this might or might not be desired way.

Answer (score 1):

You delete them in order from most childlike to most parentlike

The question is essentially aking you to read the sql as presented and use it to work out which tables are parents of other tables, then empty all the relevant records out of the child table first. There may be multiple levels of hierarchy so you need to start with tables that have no dependencies and work your way up to the root(s)

If you're only deleting a subset of the data then your delete queries have to pick out the relevant records by joining all the records back to the root where your selection criteria is to be found, and this does make things trickier

If you want a this doing for this particular case, drop a comment and I'll modify the answer. Right now I perceive this question as merely asking how it would be done in a general case

Comment: Yea i assumed it was that. Its just that in a later question, or later in the course we learned how to make a column null and then delete it and i wasnt sure if it was the same case here

Comment: Some systems use soft delete - setting a flag saying "this record is deleted" and then always using select queries that heed the flag, and the relationship is always maintained. The null method you refer to is conceptually the same as the delete method I describe here because it removes the relationship but can leave a lot of junk data lying around. Deleting the child record also removes the relationship and th data. Look up what the ON DELETE CASCADE / NULL modifiers on a foreign key do. They may both have their place, though mixing soft delete with hard delete causes problems

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, basically you need to delete everything in order (Optionally you can add all deletes in a transaction).

As I can see it should be:

1) Delete from Spossessed
DELETE FROM SPOSSSED WHERE anumber = 105;

2) Delete from Applies
DELETE FROM APPLIES WHERE anumber = 105;

3) Delete from Applicant
DELETE FROM APPLICANT WHERE anumber = 105;